# InAppSettingsKit - be able to choose multiple values

Tags: ios, inappsettings

I am using InAppSettingsKit to store user preferences in my app. I have a setting where I want the user to be able to choose multiple values for that setting (like a checkbox). Any ideas on whether I can do this using InAppSettingsKit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to do it using a checkbox kind of setup. You could try creating a group of settings, then within the group you could have an option with a toggle box for each of the values you want users to be able to select.

The only downside to this would be that you'd have to check multiple keys to check which options have been selected.

Comment: Doesn't look like there is a easy way to do this. Thanks.